# retrieving variable type from debug info

Tags: arrays, debugging, objdump, dwarf

Consider :

```
int x[] = {1, 2, 3};

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

If we do an objdump of the data section, we will get the variable x with the starting address and the size as (4*3) bytes. Is there any easy way to retrieve the information that x was an array and of what type?

I know we can do this using `dwarfdump -i a.out` and then parse the result to achieve the same, but is there anything easier which can be done? I just need to check if it was an array and of what type?

Comment: try this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003376/extract-global-variables-from-a-out-file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DWARF-reading libraries in elfutils to parse the DWARF, find the variable, and then decode its type.  This is non-trivial but the libraries do help a bit.